# Flutter application can not take reponse from any request after upgraded

Tags: android, flutter, dio

My case: After upgrade to **Flutter Channel Stable** version **2.0.5** from version **2.0.0** my app can not take res from any request to the server (I am using DIO)
No log, no debugger console, no error,...
I have tried to downgrade to 2.0.0, change the channel, clone the project into another machine, but still not resolve problem.
I was stuck for 5 days...

Here is my pubsec:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  # Packages
  flutter_onboard: ^0.1.0
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5
  flutter_screenutil: ^4.0.2+3
  pin_code_fields: ^6.0.2
  dots_indicator: ^1.2.0
  animated_bottom_navigation_bar: ^0.2.1
  circular_reveal_animation: ^1.1.5
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  expandable: ^4.1.4
  # carousel_slider: ^2.3.1
  flutter_bloc: ^6.1.1
  bloc: ^6.1.1
  rxdart: ^0.25.0
  equatable: ^1.2.3
  meta: ^1.1.8
  flutter_html: ^0.8.2
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.3.0
  flutter_easyloading: ^2.2.2
  flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.1
  sign_in_with_apple: ^2.5.4
  carousel_slider: ^3.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
  webview_flutter: ^1.0.7
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.5.0
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2+1
  package_info: ^0.4.3+4

  # firebase's packages
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.3

  # dependencies
  image_picker: ^0.7.4
  image: ^3.0.2
  flutter_svg: ^0.21.0+1
  pull_to_refresh: ^1.6.5
  device_info: ^2.0.0
  sim_info: ^0.1.3
  permission_handler: ^6.1.3
  geolocator: ^7.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3

  # easy_localization: ^2.0.2
  # http client
  http_parser: ^4.0.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.3
  http: ^0.13.1
  dio: ^4.0.0
  
dependency_overrides:
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
#  integration_test:
#    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/images/icons/
    - assets/images/graphics/
    
    - assets/svg/onboard/
    - assets/svg/icons/
    - assets/svg/graphics/

    - assets/languages/
```

Comment: ** CLOSED **
Root cause: DIO newest version conflict with other packages, just downgrade to `dio: ^3.0.10`